# Using the same data-* causing conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use data-avatarid to send it through jQuery to load the appropriate comment box modal for the Avatar.

They all have unique ID's, and are listed like so. However no matter how I've run the jQuery or changed things up. It seems to always return 8 as the avatarid.

I've tried using attr and data to get the avatarid value with no luck as well. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

This is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $('.quickComment').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('avatarid'));
      var avatarid = $(this).data("avatarid");
      $( '#quickCommentModal' ).load( 'pages/modal/quickcomment.php?ajax&avatarid='+avatarid, function( response, status, xhr ) {
        if ( status == "error" ) {
          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
          alert( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
      });
      $("#quickCommentModal").modal('show');
    });
});
```

My button code

```
<button name='quickComment' type='button' class='btn btn-info quickComment' data-avatarid='8' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Quick Comment' data-original-title='Quick Comment'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></i> 0</button>
<button name='quickComment' type='button' class='btn btn-info quickComment' data-avatarid='9' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Quick Comment' data-original-title='Quick Comment'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></i> 0</button>
<button name='quickComment' type='button' class='btn btn-info quickComment' data-avatarid='10' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Quick Comment' data-original-title='Quick Comment'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></i> 0</button>
<button name='quickComment' type='button' class='btn btn-info quickComment' data-avatarid='11' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Quick Comment' data-original-title='Quick Comment'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></i> 0</button>
```

Comment: none of the buttons shown match the selector `$('[data-toggle="avatarid"]')` ... all the toggles are `tooltip`. Sure you posted the right code?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - That's exactly what I was looking for. The only difference I notice is the document ready. Was that actually the cause of the issue? I've never experienced that before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector shown doesn't match any of the elements in html.

This one works:

```
$('button[data-avatarid]').click(function(){

  var avatarid = $(this).data("avatarid");
  alert(avatarid);

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yn7c6kLq/)**</kbd>